# how to draw a small image to filled a large container by canvas

Tags: dart, flutter

How to draw a small image to filled a large container by canvas in Flutter?

I want to use a Image, size[100, 100] to fill the screen, this is how I currently do it:

```dart
canvas.save();
canvas.scale(screenWidth / image.width,  screenHeight / image.height);
canvas.drawImage(image, Offset(0, 0), new Paint());
canvas.restore();
```

Are there any better ways to do this?

Comment: image has property to set either   fit: BoxFit.cover or fit: BoxFit.fill

Comment: use `Canvas#drawImageRect()` or better yet use `paintImage()` function from `painting` library

Comment: @Govaadiyo no, [ui.Image](http://localhost/flutter/doc-1.1.9/flutter/dart-ui/Image-class.html) does not have `fit` property

Comment: @pskink i try to use paintImage. and i found, paintImage's performance is lower than Canvas.drawImageRect.  so, what is better  of paintImage ? it's my project,[git](https://github.com/hanxu317317/flutter_plan_demo), u can test in src.bg

Comment: so use `drawImageRect` if it is enough for you

Comment: @pskink, yes, thank you